# MEAN stack: can't make post request to node server

Tags: javascript, json, node.js, angular

I'm pretty new at Angular and linking it up with node.js.
I'm trying to send a movie JSON file to my server side to save it there in my database. I set up three different files. my component with a button that gives the command (getMovie()) to save this file, my service file that tries to send a post request to the server side, and my route file on the server side that handles the POSt request.

Unfortunately I never reach the server side (there is no POST request in my logs) and I was wondering if you guys could see why?\

**Component file: here I send the JSON data to my service file**

```
import {Component} from "@angular/core";
import {ListsService} from "./lists.service";

@Component({
    selector: 'app-top100',
    templateUrl: './top100.component.html',
    styleUrls: ['./top100.component.css']
})

export class Top100Component {

    link = "https://raw.githubusercontent.com/bantic/imdb-data-scraping/master/data/movies.json"

    constructor(private listsService: ListsService){}

    Get(yourUrl){
        let Httpreq = new XMLHttpRequest(); // a new request
        Httpreq.open("GET",yourUrl,false);
        Httpreq.send(null);
        return Httpreq.responseText;
    }

    getMovie() {
        let json_obj = this.Get(this.link)
        let ls = this.listsService;
        setTimeout(function(){
            ls.saveMovies(json_obj)
        }, 3000)
}
}
```

**Service file: here I try to make a connection with the server**

```
import {Injectable} from "@angular/core";
import 'rxjs/rx';
import {Headers, Http} from "@angular/http";



// We need @injectable if we want to use http
@Injectable()

export class ListsService {

constructor(private http: Http){}

saveMovies(obj){
    const headers =  new Headers({'Content-Type': 'application/json'});
    this.http.post('http://localhost:3200/lists/savemovies', obj, {headers: headers});
}

}
```

**The lists router file on the server side**

```
var express = require('express');
var router = express.Router();


router.post('/savemovies', function(req, res, next) {
    var body = JSON.parse(req.body);
    console.log('hello');
    console.log(typeof body);
    console.log(body);
});

/* GET home page. */
router.get('/', function(req, res, next) {
    res.render('index', { title: 'Express' });
});

module.exports = router;
```

**app.js server side**

```
var express = require('express');
var path = require('path');
var favicon = require('serve-favicon');
var logger = require('morgan');
var cookieParser = require('cookie-parser');
var bodyParser = require('body-parser');
var mongoose = require('mongoose');

var appRoutes = require('./routes/app');
var listRoutes = require('./routes/lists');

var app = express();
mongoose.connect('mongodb://localhost:27017/moviemeter');

// view engine setup
app.set('views', path.join(__dirname, 'views'));
app.set('view engine', 'hbs');

// uncomment after placing your favicon in /public
//app.use(favicon(path.join(__dirname, 'public', 'favicon.ico')));
app.use(logger('dev'));
app.use(bodyParser.json());
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: false }));
app.use(cookieParser());
app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'public')));

app.use(function(req, res, next) {
  res.setHeader('Access-Control-Allow-Origin', '*');
  res.setHeader('Access-Control-Allow-Headers', 'Origin, X-Requested-With, Content-Type, Accept');
  res.setHeader('Access-Control-Allow-Methods', 'POST, GET, PATCH, DELETE, OPTIONS');
  next();
});

app.use('/lists', listRoutes);
app.use('/', appRoutes);


// catch 404 and forward to error handler
app.use(function(req, res, next) {
  res.render('index');
});

module.exports = app;
```

Comment: Update: now there is something in the log, it says "POST /lists/savemovies 500 246.098 ms - 2029
 SyntaxError: Unexpected token o in JSON at position 1"

Comment: In your service, you need to return this.http.post; and in your component, you need to subscribe to it

Comment: Ok, otherwise it won't work? I'll try to do this and get back to you.

Comment: try check received data before this line JSON.parse(req.body); Maybe you are passing some wrong data, and server fail, trying to parse it. And also don't forget to send something from /savemovies

Comment: I don't think I even reach the server. I put a simple console.log('hello') before the json.parse part, but it gives me nothing in the console.

Comment: HttpClient’s Post (or Http’s Post) returns an Observable. If you don’t subscribe to it, it never runs. Hence, it never calls your server. On the other hand, your server doesn’t return anything eitherz

Comment: core.js?223c:1440 ERROR SyntaxError: Unexpected token S in JSON at position 0
    at JSON.parse (<anonymous>)
    at Response.Body.json (webpack-internal:///749:1129:25)
    at CatchSubscriber.eval [as selector] (webpack-internal:///144:29:56)

Comment: I added observables and tried to return something on the server side. It gave me the above error.\

Comment: Update your question with the latest code please. And indicate which line gives you that error